# How do I test if my audio is already playing? Expo Audio

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using expo Audio in my React-Native project and I have managed to get a sound to play on the press of a button (hurrah!), however, if I press the play button twice, the sound plays twice over the top of each other.

I tried to disable the button once the audio has started playing and then enable it again with a .then statement, but it turns out that the .then statement gets called as soon as the audio starts (not stops). I thought I could also do this by checking if the audio is already playing, however I have had a look at the documentation and can't seem to figure out how to access the isPlaying property.

The documentation can be found here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio/

I have tried a few different console.logs to find the right information, but have not been able to access it successfully. Does anyone know how to check to see if my sound is playing? All help is much appreciated.

Here is my function:

```
  playSoundLocation = async (location) => {


        this.setState({playing: true});
        Audio.setIsEnabledAsync(true);
        const soundObject = new Audio.Sound();

       // console.log(Audio.isPlaying);

        await soundObject.loadAsync({ uri: location })
            .catch(err => { console.log(err) });

           // console.log(Audio.isPlaying);

        await soundObject.playAsync()
            .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
            .then(()=>{this.setState({playing: false})}); //calls as soon as soundstarts. Should call once ended.

            console.log(Audio);
            console.log(Audio.playbackStatus);


    }
```

***Question Edit***

I managed to change the above function to:

```
playSoundLocation = async (location) => {

        let playingResponse = false;


        if(this.state.curSoundObject !== null){
         await this.state.curSoundObject.getStatusAsync().then( response=>{playingResponse = response.isPlaying})}

        if(playingResponse === false){

            Audio.setIsEnabledAsync(true);
            const soundObject = new Audio.Sound();

            await soundObject.loadAsync({ uri: location })
                .catch(err => { console.log(err) });

            await soundObject.playAsync()
                .catch(err => { console.log(err) });

            this.setState({curSoundObject: soundObject});

    }
}
```

This function doesn't allow another sound to be played whilst one is already playing, however it does not disable the button (which would make more sense and look nicer for the user). If I add a setState I will get the same issue as before. I need to call a function once the sound has finished playing - does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What about `soundObject.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate`?

Comment: Hi, I thought this was a function used to set isPlaying: true or false. How can I see what the original value is?

Comment: Well you can use `setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate` to update the state variable `playing`, and at the very start of `playSoundLocation` you can check if the sound is playing or not, and act accordingly (play or dont play the sound). You might want to check `this.state`.

Comment: Ok, but how will I know once the sound has finished playing so that I can change the state back and re-enable the button?

Comment: I've tried to add an event listener: soundObject.addEventListener('ended', (event) => { console.log('sound has finished');}), but soundObject.addEventListener is not a function :/.